# Table bases: an endgame challenge

Tags: engines, tablebases

From where can I download this "data/syzygy/regular" file so that the code below becomes
functional ?

```
import chess

import chess.syzygy


with chess.syzygy.open_tablebase("data/syzygy/regular") as tablebase:

    board = chess.Board("8/2K5/4B3/3N4/8/8/4k3/8 b - - 0 1")

    print(tablebase.probe_wdl(board))
```

> -2

Comment: where did you get this code

Comment: imo, good question

Comment: @InertialIgnorance In the link [below](https://syzygy-tables.info/#download) there are **too many** small files. I was looking for a one or two files which I would put into that directory "data/syzygy/regular". Where can I reach them ? Or shall I download them one by one ?? :-( The code is [here](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/syzygy.html)

Comment: @user2925716 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5317668/6212530 for how to download multiple files at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

You can download the tablebases from the [Syzygy website](https://syzygy-tables.info/#download).